# Does Memgraph have a Neo4j-compatible HTTP API?

Tags: bolt, memgraphdb

A friend of mine has recommended me to write my program using Neo4j HTTP API to connect to Memgraph graphdatabase. I didn't manage to do that. Is this even possible or am I trying to do something that can not be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Memgraph doesn't support Neo4j HTTP API. You can use the Bolt protocol.  I know that it might sound strange, but Memgraph supports versions 1 and 4 of the protocol. Memgraph supports Bolt protocol drivers for following languages:

- **[Python](https://github.com/memgraph/pymgclient)**
- **[C/C++](https://github.com/memgraph/mgclient)**
- **[Rust](https://github.com/memgraph/rsmgclient)**
- **[Node.js](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver)**
- **[C#](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-dotnet-driver)**
- **[Go](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver)**
- **[Haskell](https://github.com/zmactep/hasbolt)**
- **[Java](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver)**
- **[JavaScript](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver)**
- **[PHP](https://github.com/neo4j-php/Bolt)**
- **[Ruby](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j)**